# Is Freemarker library JDK 8 ready?

Tags: freemarker

When migrating a project to JDK8, a Freemarker issue is encountered.
If the Freemarker statements
*<#if response.matchedNames??>

<#list response.matchedNames as matchedName>*
are inside the block 

*<#escape x as x?xml>*,
the Java exception below will be thrown from the freemarker-2.3.19.jar or any later versions.

*Caused by: freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: ?size is unsupported for: freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel*

These statements work well without any issue in JDK7. After debugging the application, some related info and the cause are found as below.
The property "matchedNames" of a Java object "response" is a array type. In JDK7, the property "matchedNames" is processed as ArrayModel. But in JDK8, it is processed as SimpleMethodModel.

Some more information which may help investigation is also given below. The BeanInfo introspection shows that the property type of array property is java.beans.PropertyDescriptor in JDK. However, in JDK8 the array type is interpreted as java.beans.IndexedPropertyDescriptor. Freemarker seems not handling this correctly in JDK8 and throws "?size is unsupported" for array type properties. I downloaded several later version Freemarker jar(2.3.24 - 2.3.26) and the issue is same.

Is Freemarker not JDK8 compatible? Could someone please help?

Thanks a lot,
Raymond

==============================================
A failure scenario with Java classes and freemarker template file is added as below.

Super class:

```
public class SearchByNameRes {
    protected String[] matchedNames;
    public String[] getMatchedNames() {
        return matchedNames;
    }
    public void setMatchedNames(String[] names) {
        matchedNames = names;
    }
}
```

Subclass:

```
public class SearchByAddressRes extends SearchByNameRes {
    private String[] addresses;
    public String[] getMatchedAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }
    public void setMatchedAddresses(String[] addrs) {
        addresses = addrs;
    }
}
```

Template response.ftl:

```
<Response>
<#escape x as x?xml>
    <#if response.matchedNames??>
        <#list response.matchedNames as matchedName>
        </#list>
    </#if>
</#escape>
</Response>
```

The response is an object instance of sub class SearchByAddressRes. In this simple example, the line 3 and 4 may throw the exception "freemarker.template.TemplateModelException: ?size is unsupported for: freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel".

=====================================================
Completed test code(generated from wsimport) is provided as below. The String[] type of properties may be replaced with other Java classes.

```
package test.jdk8.freemarker;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "response", propOrder = {
    "matchedNames",
    "matchedAddresses"
})
public class Response {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected String[] matchedNames;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected String[] matchedAddresses;

    public String[] getMatchedNames() {
        if (this.matchedNames == null) {
            return new String[0];
        }
        String[] retVal = new String[this.matchedNames.length] ;
        System.arraycopy(this.matchedNames, 0, retVal, 0, this.matchedNames.length);
        return (retVal);
    }

    public String getMatchedNames(int idx) {
        if (this.matchedNames == null) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return this.matchedNames[idx];
    }

    public int getMatchedNamesLength() {
        if (this.matchedNames == null) {
            return  0;
        }
        return this.matchedNames.length;
    }

    public void setMatchedNames(String[] values) {
        int len = values.length;
        this.matchedNames = ((String[]) new String[len] );
        for (int i = 0; (i<len); i ++) {
            this.matchedNames[i] = values[i];
        }
    }

    public String setMatchedNames(int idx, String value) {
        return this.matchedNames[idx] = value;
    }

    public String[] getMatchedAddresses() {
        if (this.matchedAddresses == null) {
            return new String[0];
        }
        String[] retVal = new String[this.matchedAddresses.length] ;
        System.arraycopy(this.matchedAddresses, 0, retVal, 0, this.matchedAddresses.length);
        return (retVal);
    }

    public String getMatchedAddresses(int idx) {
        if (this.matchedAddresses == null) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return this.matchedAddresses[idx];
    }

    public int getMatchedAddressesLength() {
        if (this.matchedAddresses == null) {
            return  0;
        }
        return this.matchedAddresses.length;
    }

    public void setMatchedAddresses(String[] values) {
        int len = values.length;
        this.matchedAddresses = ((String[]) new String[len] );
        for (int i = 0; (i<len); i ++) {
            this.matchedAddresses[i] = values[i];
        }
    }

    public String setMatchedAddresses(int idx, String value) {
        return this.matchedAddresses[idx] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Strange. It's supposed to be Java 8 compatible for a while (test suite runs on Java 8). If something changes from plain property with array value to an indexed property (which are supported but behave differently), that surely can break things. But you are saying you only change the Java version, and I suppose the class of the `response` object is not part of the JDK (or is it?), so that class did not change. Can you send a minimal but complete example so that I can dig into this? (Regardless of this, I would not recommend using ancient version like 2.3.19.)

Comment: @ddekany, thanks your quick reply. The only difference between 2 running application instances is JDK version. Just changed JAVA_HOME to point JDK7 and JDK8. The object "resource" is an instance of application class. And this only breaks the logic inside "<#escape x as x?xml>" block. JDK8 returns IndexedPropertyDescriptor type for protected array[] property of parent class. The array[] property of the class self is still PropertyDescriptor. Seems jdk1.8.0_77 has inconsistent behavior. Sorry for not able to provide example since the project is complex and code cannot be disclosed.

Comment: That `#escape` matters makes it even more puzzling. As if something subtle that shouldn't mater in principle make it flip in one way or the other. I understand that you can't disclose the real class, but can you create a similar class that triggers this glitch? (Also, AFAIR a `protected` method can't define properties, so it shouldn't mater... maybe that's where there was some change in Java 8? That can't explain why `#escape` matters though. Are you absolutely sure it does?)

Comment: @ddekany, I have added the simple code for the failure scenario. Please notice that the protected modifier is declared for the property in super class. Thanks

Comment: Works for me with 1.8.0_66, but the example is not complete. (Also the return type of the methods are missing, so it can't be exactly the code that you have ran.) Can you give a failing complete (standalone, run in itself) example? You are saying it fails even with the latest 2.3.x, so let's use that version.

Comment: The example is only a simple scenario which is created for replicating the issue in JDK8(I corrected the code). The test code in a large complex project will fail in JDK 8 but works well in JDK7 by only changing JDK version. It is caused by return type "IndexedPropertyDesc" of array property in JDK8(JDK7 returns PropertyDesc for array). So it is apparently Freemarker JDK version compatibility issue. The freemarker 2.3.19 and after versions have same issue. Sorry, I cannot create a standalone runnable test case since it needs lot of configuration and code for setting up freemarker. Thanks.

Comment: Also, your example doesn't define any indexed property (`IndexedPropertyDescriptor`). Those look like `String getMathcedNames(int index)`. Could you reproduce the problem with your example classes at all? Certainly in the real stuff there's indeed an indexed property, and also a non-indexed array property. Don't you have two version of that same class (same full qualified name) in the classpath there, one with, and another without an indexed property? Then it's quite random which wins.

Comment: To be honest, it is very easy to replicate the issue in JDK8. Any object with an array type property will cause the Freemarker transforming broken due to the IndexedPropertyDescriptor resolved by BeanInfo reflection logic for an array property in JDK8.

Comment: A possible easy way to get the complete test case is to use wsimport to generate some Java code from a web service. If there is array type property in a class, the Freemarker transformer function will fail.

Comment: I have tried your classes, but it works here. If merely having an array property would cause problem, the test suite wouldn't pass, and we would have received lot of complains for a long time now. There's some specialty there.

Comment: Again, can you provide some example classes that actually fail on Java 8, but not on Java 7? Did exactly those you that have shown failed? If not, and it happens with classes generated with wsimport, then send a such class.

Comment: Test Java class code was added in original post.

Comment: Right, now it fails for me too. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the behavior of `java.beans.Introspector` has changed in Java 8, if for a JavaBeans property (`marchedNames` in your case) there's both a "normal" property reader (`String[] getMatchedNames()`) and an indexed property reader (`String getMatchedNames(int)`). In such case, in Java 7, the `Introspector` only reports the "normal" property reader, while in Java 8 it reports both the "normal" and the indexed property reader. Unfortunately, when both is reported, FreeMarker prefers the last, and hence the property becomes unlistable.

What to do... one of these:

- When FreeMarker 2.3.27 is out, set `incompatibleImprovements` to 2.3.27 or higher to fix this. Note that if you aren't using the default `ObjectWrapper` of the `Configuration`, you need to set the `incompatibleImprovements` setting of the `ObjectWrapper` instance you are using, not (only) of the `Configuration`.
- Try to tell the code generator to not generate indexed property methods... but I'm not aware of such option in `wsimport`.
- Use `response.getMatchedNames()` instead of `response.matchedNames`, at least up to 2.3.26, as a workaround.

Comment: Hope the version 2.3.27 with fixes available soon. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just in case you are willing to use development versions, note that the option to fix this was committed (see updated answer).

Comment: could you please provide an approximately release date for the version 2.3.27 or any version with the fixes? thanks.

Comment: My guess is early October, but I really can't promise anything.